# HTML parsing Java result to MATLAB

Tags: java, html, matlab

I want to parse an HTML file and read its content, organize it and then use it in MATLAB 
Since I have a background in JAVA and using Jsoup to parse the HTML files, I decided to go that way and parse the HTML file from JAVA and then send the results to MATLAB. 
The problem is that my result will be an object, that I will create it, called "seizureList", and has the following entries : classification, onset, pattern, vigilance, and origin. 
How I'm supposed to convert this object from JAVA to MATLAB? 
A simple but working solution would be to write the result to a file from JAVA, And then read that file in MATLAB and parse it, but I want a more efficient way.

Note that I've gone through the other questions related to this, but they are only dealing with a string return or simple stuff, not a user defined object. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @A.Donda yes you did, sorry for being late :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Java directly from within Matlab. Then the resulting Java object would appear as a variable in the Matlab workspace, and you can access its public fields, call its methods, etc.

For more informaton, have a look at [Call Java Libraries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html) in the Matlab documentation.